# Potential causes for EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception in PhoneGap app for iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, xcode4

We're using PG 2.0 to wrap up a mobile app built with jQuery 1.8.2. We're on Xcode 4.4 and iOS 5.1.1.

We often encounter the following exception: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x130)**. The stack trace is below. Here is the output from Zombies: ***** -[UIWebOverflowScrollView _viewDelegate]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf4e0330**

We have no clue what could cause this since we're coding entirely in HTML and JavaScript, relying on PG to interface with the hardware.

Any clues? Has this happened to other PG users?

Thanks!

=============

```
libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:

0x353a3f68:  teq.w  r0, #0

0x353a3f6c:  beq    0x353a3faa                ; objc_msgSend + 66

0x353a3f6e:  push.w {r3, r4}

0x353a3f72:  ldr    r4, [r0]

0x353a3f74:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2

0x353a3f78:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8]

0x353a3f7a:  add.w  r3, r3, #8

0x353a3f7e:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]

0x353a3f82:  and.w  r9, r9, r12

0x353a3f86:  ldr.w  r4, [r3, r9, lsl #2]

0x353a3f8a:  teq.w  r4, #0

0x353a3f8e:  add.w  r9, r9, #1

0x353a3f92:  beq    0x353a3fa6                ; objc_msgSend + 62

0x353a3f94:  ldr.w  r12, [r4]

0x353a3f98:  teq.w  r1, r12

0x353a3f9c:  bne    0x353a3f7e                ; objc_msgSend + 22

0x353a3f9e:  ldr.w  r12, [r4, #8]

0x353a3fa2:  pop    {r3, r4}

0x353a3fa4:  bx     r12

0x353a3fa6:  pop    {r3, r4}

0x353a3fa8:  b      0x353a3fb0                ; objc_msgSend_uncached

0x353a3faa:  mov.w  r1, #0

0x353a3fae:  bx     lr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We removed references to -webkit-overflow-scrolling in the CSS, and this bug went away. Argh, Apple!